# If the Galois group $Aut(E/F)=A_n$，then there is no subfield $L$ such that $[L:F]=2$?

Tags: galois-theory

If the Galois group $Aut(E/F)=A_n$，then there is no subfield $L$ such that $[L:F]=2$?
I am trying to prove it by showing $A_n$ has not element to order 2, but it is easy to show this statement is not right,for example $(1,2),(3,4)$

Comment: You switched index and order. Then you know An is simple for $n\geq 5$ and just verify A3 and A4 as special cases.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want elements of order two, but rather subgroups of index $2$, which are automatically normal. Yet alternating groups of degree $5$ or more are simple.